# pgfplots - Data set doesn't get cut off

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

When doing a groupplot such as the one starting on the bottom of page 385 in the manual, is there some specific setting to cut off the data at the specified new `xmin`- and `xmax`-values? Or is there some catch to it when specifying a "lower" `xmin` value which is negative (old `xmin`: -100 -> new `xmin`: -50)?

I am using the same code, except `table` instead of `file`.

The `sharp plot` lines for the new groupplot essentially run over the end of the graph and reach into a off-screen area.

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
lmodern,
textcomp
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections,pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={group size=1 by 3},
            height=8cm,
            width=14cm,
            scale only axis=true,
            clip=false,
            %
            xlabel={Zeit},
            ylabel={Kraft},
            %
            xmajorgrids={true},
            xminorgrids={false},
            ymajorgrids={true},
            yminorgrids={false},
            enlargelimits=upper,
            ]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot[sharp plot] table [col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
            \draw[thick, dashed, red] (axis cs:-0.05,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.05,500);
            \nextgroupplot[xmin=-0.05, xmax=0.05, width=10cm]
            \addplot[sharp plot] table [col sep=semicolon] {data.csv};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### data.scv

```
Tnormiert;123123
-0.2;-5.100883
-0.198;0
-0.196;-2.550442
-0.194;-2.550442
-0.192;-2.550442
-0.19;-2.550442
-0.188;-2.550442
-0.186;-2.550442
-0.184;-2.550442
-0.182;-1.275221
-0.18;-2.550442
-0.178;-2.550442
-0.176;-2.550442
-0.174;-2.550442
-0.172;-2.550442
-0.17;-2.550442
-0.168;-2.550442
-0.166;-2.550442
-0.164;-2.550442
-0.162;-5.100883
-0.16;-2.550442
-0.158;-6.376104
-0.156;0
-0.154;-5.100883
-0.152;-1.275221
-0.15;-5.100883
-0.148;-1.275221
-0.146;-6.376104
-0.144;-2.550442
-0.142;-2.550442
-0.14;-1.275221
-0.138;0
-0.136;-6.376104
-0.134;0
-0.132;-2.550442
-0.13;-2.550442
-0.128;-5.100883
-0.126;0
-0.124;-6.376104
-0.122;0
-0.12;-2.550442
-0.118;-2.550442
-0.116;-3.825663
-0.114;-1.275221
-0.112;-2.550442
-0.11;-5.100883
-0.108;1.275221
-0.106;-5.100883
-0.104;0
-0.102;-6.376104
-0.1;0
-0.098;-2.550442
-0.096;-2.550442
-0.094;-2.550442
-0.092;-2.550442
-0.09;-2.550442
-0.088;-7.651325
-0.086;0
-0.084;-6.376104
-0.082;-2.550442
-0.08;-3.825663
-0.078;-2.550442
-0.076;-1.275221
-0.074;-3.825663
-0.072;-2.550442
-0.07;-2.550442
-0.068;-2.550442
-0.066;-2.550442
-0.064;-2.550442
-0.062;-3.825663
-0.06;-2.550442
-0.058;-5.100883
-0.056;-2.550442
-0.054;-2.550442
-0.052;-3.825663
-0.05;-2.550442
-0.048;-3.825663
-0.046;-5.100883
-0.044;-1.275221
-0.042;-2.550442
-0.04;1.275221
-0.038;-1.275221
-0.036;-3.825663
-0.034;-2.550442
-0.032;-2.550442
-0.03;0
-0.028;-2.550442
-0.026;-3.825663
-0.024;-3.825663
-0.022;-1.275221
-0.02;-1.275221
-0.018;1.275221
-0.016;-3.825663
-0.014;-2.550442
-0.012;-6.376104
-0.01;0
-0.008;-2.550442
-0.006;53.559275
-0.004;163.228268
-0.002;337.933524
0;475.657375
0.002;138.999072
0.004;-26.779638
0.006;33.155742
0.008;17.853092
0.01;3.825663
0.012;21.678754
0.014;10.201767
0.016;12.752208
0.018;33.155742
0.02;34.430963
0.022;12.752208
0.024;28.054859
0.026;15.30265
0.028;11.476988
0.03;20.403534
0.032;16.577871
0.034;20.403534
0.036;26.779638
0.038;29.330079
0.04;29.330079
0.042;35.706184
0.044;29.330079
0.046;30.6053
0.048;26.779638
0.05;24.229196
0.052;25.504417
0.054;25.504417
0.056;29.330079
0.058;30.6053
0.06;29.330079
0.062;22.953975
0.064;26.779638
0.066;19.128313
0.068;22.953975
0.07;20.403534
0.072;28.054859
0.074;26.779638
0.076;29.330079
0.078;29.330079
0.08;29.330079
0.082;26.779638
0.084;22.953975
0.086;25.504417
0.088;21.678754
0.09;26.779638
0.092;21.678754
0.094;20.403534
0.096;20.403534
0.098;17.853092
0.1;22.953975
0.102;20.403534
0.104;22.953975
0.106;21.678754
0.108;22.953975
0.11;29.330079
0.112;29.330079
0.114;29.330079
0.116;26.779638
0.118;31.880521
0.12;25.504417
0.122;28.054859
0.124;28.054859
0.126;26.779638
0.128;26.779638
0.13;26.779638
0.132;28.054859
0.134;21.678754
0.136;26.779638
0.138;24.229196
0.14;24.229196
0.142;26.779638
0.144;24.229196
0.146;30.6053
0.148;25.504417
0.15;30.6053
0.152;28.054859
0.154;25.504417
0.156;29.330079
0.158;22.953975
0.16;29.330079
0.162;26.779638
0.164;24.229196
0.166;29.330079
0.168;24.229196
0.17;29.330079
0.172;26.779638
0.174;28.054859
0.176;26.779638
0.178;28.054859
0.18;33.155742
0.182;25.504417
0.184;28.054859
0.186;28.054859
0.188;25.504417
0.19;28.054859
0.192;22.953975
0.194;28.054859
0.196;21.678754
0.198;22.953975
0.2;25.504417
0.202;20.403534
0.204;22.953975
0.206;19.128313
0.208;25.504417
0.21;20.403534
0.212;24.229196
0.214;24.229196
0.216;21.678754
0.218;29.330079
0.22;24.229196
0.222;29.330079
0.224;22.953975
0.226;28.054859
0.228;24.229196
0.23;25.504417
0.232;25.504417
0.234;26.779638
0.236;25.504417
0.238;22.953975
0.24;29.330079
0.242;24.229196
0.244;26.779638
0.246;28.054859
0.248;26.779638
0.25;29.330079
0.252;24.229196
0.254;29.330079
0.256;24.229196
0.258;29.330079
0.26;25.504417
0.262;26.779638
0.264;29.330079
0.266;26.779638
0.268;26.779638
0.27;26.779638
0.272;26.779638
0.274;29.330079
0.276;28.054859
0.278;30.6053
0.28;26.779638
0.282;33.155742
0.284;24.229196
0.286;29.330079
0.288;24.229196
0.29;28.054859
0.292;26.779638
0.294;22.953975
0.296;29.330079
0.298;22.953975
0.3;25.504417
0.302;21.678754
0.304;24.229196
0.306;25.504417
0.308;22.953975
0.31;26.779638
0.312;21.678754
0.314;25.504417
0.316;21.678754
0.318;26.779638
0.32;22.953975
0.322;24.229196
0.324;26.779638
0.326;21.678754
0.328;26.779638
0.33;24.229196
0.332;24.229196
0.334;21.678754
0.336;25.504417
0.338;24.229196
0.34;25.504417
0.342;26.779638
0.344;22.953975
0.346;28.054859
0.348;24.229196
0.35;25.504417
0.352;24.229196
0.354;25.504417
0.356;28.054859
0.358;25.504417
0.36;25.504417
0.362;25.504417
0.364;22.953975
0.366;29.330079
0.368;22.953975
0.37;26.779638
0.372;26.779638
0.374;26.779638
0.376;29.330079
0.378;24.229196
0.38;29.330079
0.382;25.504417
0.384;29.330079
0.386;29.330079
0.388;24.229196
0.39;30.6053
0.392;25.504417
0.394;26.779638
0.396;26.779638
0.398;26.779638
0.4;29.330079
0.402;22.953975
0.404;25.504417
0.406;24.229196
0.408;24.229196
0.41;26.779638
0.412;25.504417
0.414;26.779638
0.416;21.678754
0.418;26.779638
0.42;24.229196
0.422;25.504417
0.424;24.229196
0.426;20.403534
0.428;25.504417
0.43;21.678754
0.432;26.779638
0.434;24.229196
0.436;24.229196
0.438;24.229196
0.44;25.504417
0.442;25.504417
0.444;22.953975
0.446;26.779638
0.448;24.229196
0.45;24.229196
0.452;24.229196
0.454;24.229196
0.456;26.779638
0.458;24.229196
0.46;25.504417
0.462;24.229196
0.464;24.229196
0.466;26.779638
0.468;22.953975
0.47;28.054859
0.472;25.504417
0.474;26.779638
0.476;28.054859
0.478;22.953975
0.48;26.779638
0.482;25.504417
0.484;26.779638
0.486;26.779638
0.488;26.779638
0.49;29.330079
0.492;24.229196
0.494;29.330079
0.496;25.504417
0.498;28.054859
0.5;26.779638
0.502;24.229196
0.504;29.330079
0.506;24.229196
0.508;26.779638
0.51;26.779638
0.512;25.504417
0.514;26.779638
0.516;22.953975
0.518;29.330079
0.52;21.678754
0.522;24.229196
0.524;24.229196
0.526;21.678754
0.528;26.779638
0.53;20.403534
0.532;25.504417
0.534;25.504417
0.536;25.504417
0.538;24.229196
0.54;25.504417
0.542;28.054859
0.544;21.678754
0.546;28.054859
0.548;21.678754
0.55;25.504417
0.552;22.953975
0.554;22.953975
0.556;28.054859
0.558;24.229196
0.56;24.229196
0.562;26.779638
0.564;20.403534
0.566;24.229196
0.568;28.054859
0.57;24.229196
0.572;24.229196
0.574;25.504417
0.576;21.678754
0.578;29.330079
0.58;26.779638
0.582;25.504417
0.584;26.779638
0.586;24.229196
0.588;26.779638
0.59;26.779638
0.592;24.229196
0.594;29.330079
0.596;26.779638
0.598;26.779638
0.6;28.054859
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `clip=false` in the `groupplot` options, so this would happen. Make it `clip=true`.

If you had any other paths (`\draw`, `\node` etc.) that went outside the axis limits, you could add `clip mode=individual` to enable clipping of plot lines but not other paths within the axis. That is not needed here however.